# Laravel - Guzzle post request with params

Tags: json, laravel, guzzle, guzzle6

I'am trying to receive json response from post request with guzzle but i can't understand if i'm wrong about this or it's an API vendor problem.

First

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

This is my code in Boats Controller

```
public function index()
{
$client = new Client();
$res=$client>post("http://ws.nausys.com/CBMSexternal/rest/catalogue/v6/charterBases",
                [
                'auth' =>  ['*****@****', '********'],
                'headers' => [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json']
                ]);
echo $res->getBody();

}
```

Route in web.php

```
//Ruote Boats
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.boats'),('Boats@index'), function () {
});
```

> Client error: `POST
>   http://ws.nausys.com/CBMS-external/rest/catalogue/v6/charterBases`
>   resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
>   "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: Sems a problem with http://ws.nausys.com/CBMS-external/rest/catalogue/v6/charterBases, check if the request to that server respect the api interface. Can you reproduce the same call with Postman?

Comment: @SergioDonati i'm just do a try with Postman, I had never used it but it seems to give the same result as Laravel. 400 Bad request.               https://pasteboard.co/J8Etcq3.png                               
https://pasteboard.co/J8EtIxI.png

Comment: so the problem is with the host of your request and not a Larave/PHP/Guzzle problem.
You have to check the api doc of the server you try to reach.
I don't know http://ws.nausys.com/CBMS-external/rest/catalogue/v6/charterBases what is.